# How is 側 used in this sentence?

Tags: readings, sentence, pronouns

> つまり、狂化者を生み出した側の予測を上回る狂化者

my reading is akin "A mad person who surpasses the mad person creator's prediction "

However, what is this meaning of 側の? "Is it "third person"? Or it may be "side"? "The side who creates mad people"?

Comment: I wonder why you thought it could refer to a third person. 側 almost always refers to one of the two sides.

Answer (score 2):

It is literally *the side*.

As you understand correctly, 狂化者を生み出した側の予測 is *the prediction on the 狂化者 creator's side*.